# Henkin/branching quantifier: say what?

Tags: predicate-logic, quantifiers

This is a substantial revision of the original question, to cut out material that turned out to be irrelevant. Most of the comments and answers and comments-to-answers relate to the O.P. so are no longer applicable.

The question was triggered by a bald sub-heading in [this informal write-up](https://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2010/01/17/a-limit-of-first-order-logic/)

**A Problem With First Order Logic**

The author doesn't say what specific example he was working with, but gives a simpler case

$$
S(x,y,a,b) \text{ could be } (a^2 = x) \wedge (b^2 = y) 
$$

He wants to express $\forall x, y ... [S(x, y, a, b)]$ in which $a$ is dependent purely on $x$, $b$ dependent purely on $y$; and those (in)dependencies is what he wants to express in the $...$.

That simpler case using roots is expressible in FOL, so is too over-simplified to illustrate anything.

He goes on to introduce 'Henkin' aka 'Branching' quantifiers. So his general case could be expressed as

$$
\pmatrix{\forall x \exists a\\ \forall y \exists b}S(x, y, a, b)
$$

Although this appears to involve quantifying only over individuals, its semantics are in fact given in (a restricted form of) Second-Order. So the sub-heading's 'Problem with First Order Logic' is that it is not Second Order. Nothing to see here; move right along.

Some relevant resources: [wikipedia branching quantifier](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_quantifier%20wikipedia%20Branching%20quantifier); [Stanford Encyclopedia Dependence logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-dependence/); [a critique of so-called 'Hintikka sentences' with their claim of non-expressibility in FOL](http://www.jakubszymanik.com/papers/HTR.pdf). I found math.stackexchange had very little, hence this question. Google has lots of hits but mostly about Henkin's contributions to logic in general.

Then the nub of my question (before I realised a Henkin quantifier is merely Second-Order in sheep's clothing) was: I just don't get what the examples in those write-ups are trying to say that can't be said in FOL.

tl;dr: some Second-Order formulas (including some using Henkin quantification) can be equivalently expressed in FOL; some can't. Again nothing to see here. The literature (including in the Stanford Encyclopedia) mostly shows examples that in fact can be expressed in FOL. Again perhaps over-simplifying for the sake of explanation.

@Noah's answer below brings forward an example entailing an infinitary model; it is substantially more complex than the natural language examples in the literature.

A note for non-maths readers: I came at this from Dependency Theory in the database Relational Model, which is entirely equivalently expressible in FOL. That's a different sense of "Dependenc/y".

Comment: I think this question would benefit from having some verbiage pruned away (especially, frankly, any phrases like "I was shocked and horrified at the allegation").

Comment: @antc, the problem with the irrelevant bits is that it makes it less likely for anyone who can answer you to read through. I would not be able to answer because I know little logic, but I was simply not able to understand clearly what you are asking, for example. (And you can use latex here...)

Comment: OK @Mariano, I posted a shorter/punchier version of the question. And with proper symbols -- which I was going to do here, except answers came too fast. Yes I know I can use latex; it's remembering which markup to use from all of the different forums I post on.

Comment: @antc, no: please delete the new post and edit **this** one. We don't want two different versions of the same post — what possible good .ight come out of that?!.  And it is in really poor taste to leave Noah's amazing answer behind. People put a lot of work in writing answers such as his, you know.

Comment: @AntC What? I didn't paste an answer from elsewhere, and I did try to understand what was confusing you. I've responded to your comments below my answer to try to improve things. I'm sorry I haven't succeeded yet, but frankly I'm annoyed at this response. I think you should try to work a little more cooperatively in the future with the people trying to answer your questions (and again, language like "shocked and horrified by the allegation" **really** has no place here).

Comment: @AntC, your whole attitude seems to be designed to alianate anyone with the will to help you, really. I simply cannot believe your tone and your treatment of Noah.

Comment: It's just struck me why the Hintikka examples seem so familiar: that crossing co-reference idea is the source of the Bach-Peters paradox. Sorry can't find a better ref than this on a quick search: https://web.stanford.edu/~laurik/publications/archive/crossing.pdf. The classic sentence is "The pilot who shot at it hit the Mig that chased him." This needs two existential quants co-referencing. It's been formalised by Montague Grammarians (who are logicians, despite the name). The 'less formal write-up' example isn't like those. I'm increasingly thinking it _doesn't_ need a branching quantifier.

Comment: "When I post an answer, it helps to know where the q is coming from/what's the questioner's current level of knowledge." There's a difference between that and letting your question explode into a rant. Seriously, language like "shocked and horrified" has no place on MSE. Motivation doesn't need to reflect your own personal indignation at nonintuitive results.

Comment: Not only are the results I posted about non-intuitive, they're wrong: Lipton's 'less formal write-up' fails to illustrate the need for Henkin quantifier; the critique I ref below from Univ Amsterdam (linked from wp) says (now that I've worked through it) 'Hintikka sentences' can be expressed with ordinary linear quantification. Whether H is needed for the Ehrenfeucht example you raised (wasn't in my O.P.) remains to be seen; but you should be indignant that H is surrounded by mis-information. I wouldn't have figured out any of that without the dialogue here, so thank you.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Based on the comments below, let me explain in detail the key point:

> There is **no** first-order sentence $\theta$ which is true in exactly the infinite structures.

Proof: Suppose $\theta$ is a first-order sentence true in exactly the infinite structures. We'll consider its negation, $\neg\theta$; by our assumption on $\theta$, $\neg\theta$ is true in exactly the finite structures.

So what? Well, we use the [**compactness theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactness_theorem). This is in my opinion the most important basic result in logic, and is definitely the first thing you want to master to understand first-order logic and its extensions. The compactness theorem says that if $\Gamma$ is a set of first-order sentences, and every finite subset of $\Gamma$ has a model, then $\Gamma$ itself has a model.

For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $\chi_n$ be the sentence $$\exists x_1\exists x_2...\exists x_n(\bigwedge_{i<j\le n} x_i\not=x_j).$$ Each $\chi_n$ is a first-order sentence which is true in exactly those structures with at least $n$ elements. Now let's think about the set of sentences $$\Gamma=\{\chi_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{\neg\theta\}.$$

Any finite subset $\Gamma_0\subseteq\Gamma$ is satisfiable: if we let $k\in\mathbb{N}$ be large enough so that no $\chi_m$ is in $\Gamma_0$ for $m\ge k$ *(note that such a $k$ exists since $\Gamma_0$ is finite!)*, we see that any structure of size at least $k$ satisfies $\Gamma_0$. But $\Gamma$ itself has no model: any model of $\{\chi_n: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ must be infinite, but no infinite structure is a model of $\neg\theta$. So we have our contradiction. $\quad\Box$

Note that we can write this as a direct proof instead, showing:

> If $\eta$ is a first-order sentence with arbitrarily large finite models, then $\eta$ has an infinite model.

(Above, take $\neg\theta$ to be $\eta$.)

The two crucial facts we've used about first-order logic are:

- The compactness theorem, and
- the fact that first-order logic has negation.

It turns out, surprisingly, that the *latter* is the issue with dependence(-style) logic(s)! But that's something we should look at only after we understand the basic argument above in detail.

---

The bulk of this question I find difficult to follow; let me address the main question:

> I just don't get what the examples in those write-ups are trying to say that can't be said in FOL.

I think it's easier to just do an explicit example: a sentence $\varphi$ using a Henkin quantifier, in the empty language, which is true exactly if the ambient domain is infinite. Namely, $$\varphi\equiv\exists zQ(x, y; a, b)[a\not=z\wedge (x\not=y\iff a\not=b)].$$ (Here I'm writing "$Q(x, y; a, b)$" to denote "for all $x, y$ there are $a, b$ depending only on $x, y$ respectively such that.")

OK, it's probably not clear what $\varphi$ *means*, so let's take it apart.

The semantics of branching quantifiers is best described, in my opinion, in terms of [Skolem functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_normal_form). According to this semantics we can express $\varphi$ in second-order logic as $$\hat{\psi}\equiv\exists F_1, F_2, z\forall x, y[(F_1(x)\not=z)\wedge (F_1(x)=F_2(y)\iff x=y)].$$ However, I claim we can do one better, and express it as $$\psi\equiv \exists z, F\forall x, y(F(x)\not=z\wedge (x\not=y\implies F(x)\not=F(y))).$$ *(Note that here "$\iff$" isn't needed since we're only using one function symbol now - "$x=y\implies F(x)=F(y)$" is a tautology.)* Clearly we have $\psi\implies\hat{\psi}$ *(take $F_1=F_2=F$)*; conversely, the point is that in order for a pair of Skolem functions $F_1, F_2$ to witness that $\hat{\psi}$ is true we must have $F_1=F_2$ (if $F_1(a)\not=F_2(a)$ for $a$ in the domain, then $x=a, y=a$ would give a counterexample to $\psi$).

Now looking at $\psi$, we see that $\psi$ asserts the existence of an injection from the model to itself (namely, $F$) which is not surjective (it misses $z$). So $\psi$ is a sentence **true in every infinite structure** but **false in every finite structure**, and by the compactness theorem (and the argument above) this can't happen in a first-order way.

---

Let me try to give a quick "moral" of the story. The crucial point of difference between first-order and dependence sentences here is:

> When Skolemizing a first-order sentence in prenex normal form, each existential quantifier corresponds to a function taking as inputs *all* variables in prior universal quantifiers.

E.g. the Skolemized version of the first-order sentence $$\forall x\forall y\exists z\forall u\exists v(\theta(x, y, z, u, v))$$ is $$\exists F\exists G\forall x\forall y\forall u(\theta(x, y, F(x, y), u, G(x, y, u))).$$

By contrast, in a dependence sentence we have more freedom with regard to how the Skolem functions are "entangled," and we've seen that in play above.

---

Now let me try to explain the claim that dependence logic only involves quantifying over individuals (a claim, incidentally, that I disagree with). What dependence logic does is argue that general expressions of the form $$\mbox{[second-order existential quantifiers](first-order formula)}$$ form a natural generalization of first-order sentences while staying in the realm of quantification over individuals, since all the new power we get this way really just comes down to expressing dependencies. (These are in fact essentially the sentences expressible in dependence logic.)

I haven't treated here the question of whether dependence logic is in fact more first-order or more second-order. Vaanaanen has written at length in defense of the former position; personally, I take the latter view. But you asked specifically for something expressible using dependencies which isn't first-order expressible, and I've done that above. So hopefully this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Noah. I've seen that 'empty language' example before. I don't know what I don't know (hence my verbiage in the q). What is 'empty language'? Why do you think that's going to help if I don't understand the more natural examples? That formula doesn't look like an example of anything/it looks ... empty. Using a Henkin quantifier to explain what is a Henkin quantifier isn't helping: I didn't ask what can be expressed with a Henkin quantifier; I asked what _can't_ be expressed in FOL.

Comment: I know of skolemisation/Skolem functions, and the Stanford entry tries a Second-Order explanation. But _if_ it's a function, it has a single result. Whereas what seems critical in the less abstract examples is that there are multiple `a`s (at least one) dependent on `x`, treated as a set. Then I don't see that using a function is even capable of expressing the logic. I'd expect a predicate of the form `exists P exists a [ P(x, a) implies ... a ... ]` to express there might be multiple `a`s. It's no surprise something Second-Order is more expressive than FOL; that also wasn't the question.

Comment: Since I don't understand the semantics of the Henkin qualifier (it's apparently not just shorthand for some cumbersome FOL formula); then I don't know what would be the negation thereof. What does 'apply compactness' mean? So nothing is 'easy to show'. I'll add some more to the q (sorry) to show why I think the example _is_ first-order expressible.

Comment: @AntC "What does 'apply compactness' mean? So nothing is 'easy to show'" See my edit (fourth paragraph); I explain why there is no sentence true in exactly those structures which are infinite, whereas I've given an example of a sentence using a Henkin quantifier which *is*. "What is 'empty language'?" Remember that a "language" in this context is a possibly empty set of function, constant, and relation symbols; the empty language is when we don't have any of those, that is, we only have logical symbols (including equality and variables). (cont'd)

Comment: "That formula doesn't look like an example of anything/it looks ... empty." Do you understand why the sentence I've written down is true in exactly those structures which are infinite? If not, why not? "Why do you think that's going to help if I don't understand the more natural examples?" Because I think that "natural" examples are often *more* complicated, by bringing in unnecessary intuitions.

Comment: @AntC OK, let's step back a bit - do you see why the *second-order* sentence $\psi$ is true exactly when the domain is infinite, and why no first-order sentence can be this way?  (Re: your other questions: "It needs to be an infinite domain? Then the Stanford and Hintikka examples are bogus." No, I'm saying that the domain needs to be infinite in order for the specific sentence I wrote down to be true. "It needs to be in empty language? Why don't any of the references say that?" No it doesn't need to be in the empty language, I'm just trying to make an example which is as simple as possible.)

Comment: Thank you again @Noah. I've now worked through your sentence `ψ`, and can see it needs the domain to be infinite for it to be true. I don't see why a first-order sentence couldn't entail an infinite domain. First-order `∀, ∃` can apply for infinite domains. `∃ b` just requires we find some suitable `b` to make the sentence true, for each `y`. It doesn't entail there's a function or 'definite procedure' to discover it. I have a first-order sentence equivalent to your `φ` (or at least to my understanding of it). Where shall I post that?

Comment: @AntC You can post it here in the comments, and we can analyze it. Meanwhile, I'll update my answer to explain in more detail why such a sentence cannot in fact exist.

Comment: Thank you @Noah for your patience. I'll try to work through what you've added. I feel very uncomfortable dealing with infinite structures. I don't understand why first-order sentences can't be true in infinite structures (linear recursion is still first-order); I don't understand why the negation of a sentence true in the infinite structures must be true only for finite structures. (Can't the negation still be true in infinite structures?) I thought the Peano axioms are first-order; and the Naturals are infinite last time I checked. My counter-sentence is way too long to post in a comment.

Comment: @AntC It's not that they can't be true in infinite structures, it's that they can't be true in **exactly** the infinite structures: there is no first-order sentence $\theta$ such that $\mathcal{M}\models\theta$ **if and only if** $\mathcal{M}$ is infinite. Note that by definition of the semantics for "$\neg$", if $\mathcal{M}\models\theta$ iff $\mathcal{M}$ is infinite, then $\mathcal{M}\models\neg\theta$ iff $\mathcal{M}$ is finite.

Comment: For example, the sentence "$\forall x(x=x)$" is true in every infinite structure, but it's also true in every finite structure (so isn't true in only infinite structures); and the sentence "$\forall x, y(x*y=y*x)$" is true in every infinite abelian group, but is not true in any infinite nonabelian group (so isn't true in every infinite structure).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks for this post.  I think you may need $$\varphi\equiv\exists zQ(x, y; a, b)[a\not=z\wedge (x\not=y \color{red} \iff a\not=b)]$$ to indicate that $a(x)$ and $b(y)$ are the same function, otherwise (if I'm reading it right) the formula is satisfied in a finite domain by $a(x) = 0$, $b(y) = 1$, witness $z = 2$.

Comment: It says [here p152](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d534/a7ea4bdcf2f77ba17c7c17fb20dae5dfa3f9.pdf) "The first known sentence with a Henkin quantifier not expressible in elementary logic is the so-called Ehrenfeucht statement:" This is essentially the negation of @Noah's $\varphi$ with bi-implication. Saying "the first known" suggests to me that the positive form -- i.e. bare $\varphi$ _is_ expressible in FOL.

Comment: @AntC DanielV was correct, I've fixed my example to include "$\iff$." However, my second-order analysis *is correct*, and I've explained why. $\varphi$ (with bi-implication) is indeed true in exactly the infinite structures, and by the compactness theorem this can't happen in a first-order way as I've described. Re: the paper you've mentioned: first of all, note that if a sentence isn't expressible in a first-order way, then neither is its negation. So the Ehrenfeucht sentence being non-first-order *also* means that my $\varphi$ above is non-first-order. (continued)

Comment: Meanwhile, with regard to your claimed first-orderization of $\varphi$, my suspicion (I haven't had a chance to look at it in detail yet) is that it is not true in **every** infinite structure. Remember that the whole point of $\varphi$ is that it be true in **every** infinite structure and **no** finite structure.

Comment: You've editted the answer to explain the move from two Skolem functions $\mathbf{F_1}, \mathbf{F_2}$ to single $\mathbf{F}$. Yes that means you can "do one better"; but you've slipped into a SOL formula that no longer corresponds to the definition of the Henkin quantifier. That there is a SOL formula not expressible in FOL is no surprise; and is not a counter-example.

Comment: "$x = y \Longrightarrow \mathbf{F}(x) = \mathbf{F}(x)$ _is a tautology._" Yes. But the _bi_-implication also gives $\mathbf{F}(x) = \mathbf{F}(x) \Longrightarrow x = y$ which isn't.

Comment: @AntC You're misunderstanding the point. I've shown that $\varphi$ is equivalent to $\psi$, and this means that $\varphi$ is true in exactly the infinite structures. And this is something no first-order sentence can do. Do you disagree that $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are equivalent?

Comment: @Noah I accept $\psi$, $\hat{\psi}$ are equivalent, by the definition of quantifier $\mathbf{Q}$. You say "we have $\psi\implies\hat{\psi}$ ". I'd dispute your "clearly" (the absence of the bi-implication is troubling). Even if I accept, that's still only one-way implication, _not_ "equivalent".

Comment: @AntC You can make it a bi-implication if you want, but that's redundant (we really **do** clearly have "$x=y\implies F(x)=F(y)$" as a tautology in first-order logic - I don't know what could be clearer than that!). And the implication "$\hat{\psi}\implies \psi$" is described in the very next sentences ("conversely ..."). The two sentences really are equivalent.

Comment: Please re-read what I said (and what your answer says). I'm not disagreeing with your tautology. It's that I'm not seeing that its reverse holds. Look again at where your answer says "clearly". If your claim is true of non-FOL expressibility, then please show it for the version with $\mathbf{F_1}, \mathbf{F_2}$. Then we don't have to worry about equivalence. Or we could just stop. (Probably I'll never understand the compactness theorem, nor what you're saying about $¬\theta$.) My initial alarm about the Lipton piece and the 'Hintikka sentences' has turned out to be due to false examples.

Comment: @AntC I truly don't understand what you're missing. I used the compactness theorem to prove that there is no first-order sentence true in exactly the infinite first-order structures. I showed that the sentence $\varphi$ is equivalent to $\psi$, and showed that $\psi$ is true in exactly the infinite structures ... and putting all this together, concluded that $\varphi$ is not equivalent to any first-order sentence. I really don't understand what piece is missing here.

Comment: I'm going to bow out now, since I can't figure out how to explain this to you. If you can make your confusion more precise, you can ask a separate question about it and someone else might be able to help.

Comment: Thank you @Noah, yes let's call it a day. "I truly don't understand what you're missing. " Probably several degree courses in Higher Math and Logic ;-). (My degree is in Philosophy, concentrating on traditional Natural Language semantics and Empiricism. I use FOL for relational database semantics and inference.) I've trimmed down the question to remove what turned out to be irrelevant. That made many of the comments not applicable, so I deleted most of mine. You might want to do the same.

Answer (score -1):

This is a response to/critique of @Noah's answer and comprehensive explanation (thank you again). I offer an alternative formulation, which is why I'm posting as an answer.

tl;dr:

- I can see Noah's formula $\psi$ is true only in infinite structures,
  and skolem function $\mathbf{F}$ must be injective but not surjective.
  I give my workings, to verify I'm on the right page.
- In moving from the Henkin-quantified $\varphi$ to $\psi$, there seems to be a step omitted.
  I give grounds why that makes them not equivalent.
- I give a formulation for $\varphi$ which is first-order.

  **Edit:** Per @DanielV's comment on Noah's answer, I've changed the formulas to use $\Longleftrightarrow$ rather than $\Longrightarrow$.

**Only infinite structures:**

For definiteness, take the domain to be the Naturals. The formula begins $\psi\equiv\exists z,\mathbf{F} ...$. We can take $z$ as some arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{N}$. For $\psi$ to be true, the skolem function $\mathbf{F}$ must never produce $n$, because then $a\neq z$ would fail. Then we could choose:

$$
\begin{align}
 & \mathbf{F}(x) = x + 1 & , x = n\\
 & \mathbf{F}(x) = x & , x < n  & \hspace{20pt}\text{-- no danger of producing n}\\
 & \mathbf{F}(x) = x + 1 & , x > n
\end{align}
$$

Why produce $x + 1$ if already $x > n$? Remember $\mathbf{F}$ is blind as to whether it's applying to $x$ so producing $a$ or applying to $y$ so producing $b$. Consider the case in $P(z, x, y, \mathbf{F}(x), \mathbf{F}(y))$ of $x = n, y = n+1$. We have $x\neq y$ so for the implication to hold we must have $\mathbf{F}(x) \neq \mathbf{F}(y)$. Then consider $x = n+1, y = n+2$, and so on. So $x+1$ ripples all the way up the domain. We cannot choose to stop short of infinity.

$\mathbf{F}$ must be **not surjective** because it must never produce $n$; otherwise $a\neq z$ would fail. $\mathbf{F}$ must be **injective** because for each distinct input it must produce a unique result; otherwise the implication $(x\neq y \Longleftrightarrow F(x)\neq\mathbf{F}(y))$ would fail.

**Step from Henkin-quantified to Second-Order skolem function:**

For $\varphi\equiv\exists z, \mathbf{Q}(x,y;a,b)[ ... ]$ Noah writes

> (Here I'm writing $\mathbf{Q}(x, y; a, b)$ to denote "forall $x,y$ there are $a,b$ depending only on $x,y$ respectively such that.")

If this were FOL, we'd say we could represent that dependence by two skolems: one for $a$, one for $b$.

> In more natural language, $\varphi$ states the existence of a function from the domain to itself [**] which is injective but not surjective.

I agree with the "injective but not surjective", see above. I do not agree with the "a function" [singular]. We have two skolems, I expect two functions. I think $\varphi$ should be:

$$
\varphi'\equiv\exists z,\mathbf{F}', \mathbf{G}'\forall x,y[\mathbf{F}'(x)\neq z\wedge(x\neq y \Longleftrightarrow \mathbf{F}'(x)\neq\mathbf{G}'(y))].
$$

I can see of course that $\varphi'$ will only be true providing $\mathbf{F}', \mathbf{G}'$ are the same function. I've no idea how to prove that -- especially in an infinite model.

Note this has $\exists \mathbf{G}'$ quantified inside $\exists z,\mathbf{F}'$. So $\mathbf{G}'$ is dependent on $z$ (fair enough) but also dependent on $\mathbf{F}'$. Of course $\mathbf{G}'$ is a function therefore whose result is produced purely from $y$. The *choice of function* for $\mathbf{G}'$ is dependent on the choice of function for $\mathbf{F}'$. (They must be the same.) We seem to be back at the problem we started with. (**Edit:** No, the natural language 'dependent on' isn't the technical Dependence Logic sense. The $\exists$ can be permuted without losing logical equivalence; so they're not dependent.)

Noah does consider the way two skolems would be treated in FOL, as two functions. This example is carefully constructed so that we can use the same function $\mathbf{F}$ to produce both dependent values. That won't be the case in general.

I'm pointing this out because in all the examples I'm looking at of 'Hintikka sentences' [Section 1](http://www.jakubszymanik.com/papers/HTR.pdf), (reference from wikipedia on 'Branching quantifier'), I see exactly this sort of entanglement of choices to instantiate the dependent variables. Perhaps they're all poorly chosen examples. I'm increasingly thinking the Lipton 'less formal write-up' is poorly chosen.

**EDIT:** Furthermore the semantics Henkin gives for his own quantifier introduce two skolem functions -- that's the same paper, top of p 368.

([**] BTW neither do I agree with "from the domain to itself". We could have $z, a, b$ in a distinct domain from $x, y$. Then $x, y$'s domain could be finite; $z, a, b$'s would need to be larger by at least one. How does that affect the justification?)

**First-Order formulation:**

$$\begin{align}
\exists z & [ \forall x \exists a \forall y \exists b & [a\neq z\wedge(x\neq y\Longleftrightarrow a\neq b)\\
 &  & \wedge \forall x', y', a', b' & [a'\neq z\wedge(x'\neq y'\Longleftrightarrow a'\neq b')\\
 &  &   & \Longrightarrow (a\neq z\wedge(x\neq y'\Longleftrightarrow a\neq b') \wedge a'\neq z\wedge(x'\neq y\Longleftrightarrow a'\neq b)] ]\\
 & \wedge \forall y \exists b \forall x \exists a & [a\neq z\wedge(x\neq y\Longleftrightarrow a\neq b)\\
 &  & \wedge \forall x', y', a', b' & [a'\neq z\wedge(x'\neq y'\Longleftrightarrow a'\neq b')\\
 &  &   & \Longrightarrow (a'\neq z\wedge(x\neq y'\Longleftrightarrow a\neq b') \wedge a'\neq z\wedge(x'\neq y\Longleftrightarrow a'\neq b)] ]\\
 & ].
\end{align}
$$

The two branches mixing up the $∀x ∃a ∀y ∃b$ vs $∀y ∃b ∀x ∃a$ are per the strong form formula (5) in the 'Hintikka sentences' paper above. They ensure we get (a version of the assertion with) *both* $a$ dependent purely on $x$ *and* $b$ dependent purely on $y$.

The embedded $∀x', y', a', b'$ within each branch says: whereever you get $x', y', a', b'$ such that $a'\neq z\wedge(x'\neq y'\Longleftrightarrow a'\neq b')$ holds, you must be able to permute the dependencies $x ↦ a, y \mapsto b$.

Then the only solutions for which the overall formula holds is when $b$ is chosen independently of $x$, $a$ is chosen independently of $y$.

That is, if that is a genuine requirement in this example. (I'm suspecting not.)

Comment: What is "$P$" in your claimed first-order formulation of $\varphi$? Note that if $P$ is just a unary predicate symbol, then your sentence is **false** in any structure where $P$ doesn't hold of anything, so this gives us an infinite structure in which your statement is false.

Comment: Re: "We have two skolems, I expect two functions." see my recent edit: you **can** in fact reduce to a single Skolem function (once we fix the bi-implication issue that DanielV pointed out).

Comment: "P" is just shorthand for the matrix of your $\varphi$/ non-negated Ehrenfeucht statement, as I said at the top. I'll need to adjust it to use bi-implication.

Answer (score -1):

> something couldn't be expressed in FOL, but still only involved quantifying over individuals, not predicates (which would make it Second-Order).

(That's the opening of my question.)

The semantics of the Henkin quantifier are given in [wikipedia 'Branching quantifier' Definition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_quantifier#Definition_and_properties). But I didn't want to rely entirely on that. It turns out the original Henkin 1961 paper (behind a pay wall) explored a family of quantifiers. This is the most basic. The semantics in wikipedia agree with [this critique cited by wp](http://www.jakubszymanik.com/papers/HTR.pdf) and [this survey](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d534/a7ea4bdcf2f77ba17c7c17fb20dae5dfa3f9.pdf).

> The simplest Henkin quantifier $Q_{H}$ is

$$
(Q_{H}x_{1},x_{2},y_{1},y_{2})\phi (x_{1},x_{2},y_{1},y_{2})\equiv {\begin{pmatrix}\forall x_{1}\exists y_{1}\\ \forall x_{2}\exists y_{2}\end{pmatrix}}\phi (x_{1},x_{2},y_{1},y_{2}).
$$

> It (in fact every formula with a Henkin prefix, not just the simplest one) is equivalent to its second-order Skolemization, i.e.

$$
\exists f\exists g\forall x_{1}\forall x_{2}\phi (x_{1},x_{2},f(x_{1}),g(x_{2})).
$$

Then Henkin has introduced some notation mentioning only individuals, that he's defining as equivalent to a Second-Order formula. That's fine: the claim is there's a Second-Order formula that (in general) can't be expressed in FOL. No need to question that.

Of course any FOL formula with $\exists$ quantification of individuals might be written using Second-Order Skolemisation functions. Again nothing to see here. Whether the Lipton 'less formal write-up' case can be expressed in FOL is a side-issue: Lipton has perhaps chosen a poor example which doesn't need the expressive power of a Henkin quantifier.

Noah's answer gives an informal description of the Henkin quantifier:

> (Here I'm writing "$Q(x,y;a,b)$" to denote "for all $x,y$ there are $a,b$ depending only on $x,y$ respectively such that.")

Does Henkin's Skolemisation $\exists f \exists g$ achieve the effect of '$a$ depending only on $x$; $b$ depending only on $y$'? (To paraphrase slightly.)

Certainly $f(x)$ depends only on $x$ and $g(y)$ depends only on $y$. But putting $\exists f \exists g$ has merely introduced a different dependency: $f, g$ must be chosen together.

**EDIT: What is a dependence, anyway?**

In that last paragraph, I used "dependency" in a natural language sense. But "(in)dependent" seems to have a technical sense here: related-but-different to the natural language sense or the database Dependency Theory sense. To explain by example:

- A $\forall$ quantified variable is always dependent only on the domain; therefore 'independent' of any other variable.
- Two adjacent $\exists$ quantifications are not 'dependent', because permuting them yields a logically equivalent formula. [That is](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Provable_identities):
  $$
  \exists x \exists y \phi \equiv \exists y \exists x \phi
  $$

  Then this is what the Henkin Skolemisation is relying on to claim it has $f, g$ 'independent' -- in this technical sense.
- Adjacent $\forall x \exists y$ cannot in general be permuted and retain logical equivalence.
  $$
  \forall x \exists y \phi \not\equiv \exists y \forall x \phi
  $$

  The rules of this language game have already decided the $\forall x$ isn't 'dependent', so it must be that permuting $\exists y$ to its right makes $y$ 'dependent'. Informally $\forall x \exists y$ means we might need to choose a different $y$ for each $x$ in order to make $\phi$ true for that $x$. Whereas $\exists y \forall x$ asserts we need only find a single $y$ such that $\phi$ holds for each $x$.

OK. The test is logical equivalence of formulas. Then in general
$$
\forall x_{1} \exists y_{1} \forall x_{2} \exists y_{2} \phi \not\equiv \forall x_{2} \exists y_{2} \forall x_{1} \exists y_{1} \phi
$$

And we have to say the rightmost $\exists y_{n}$ is 'dependent' on *all* the $\forall x_{n}$ to its left.

But, but, but! If the test is logical equivalence (and only that) we can easily arrange to say we require the two formulations to be equivalent:

$$\begin{align}
& \forall x_{1} \exists y_{1} \forall x_{2} \exists y_{2} \phi\\
\wedge & \forall x_{2} \exists y_{2} \forall x_{1} \exists y_{1} \phi\\
\wedge & (\forall x_{1} \exists y_{1} \forall x_{2} \exists y_{2} \phi \equiv \forall x_{2} \exists y_{2} \forall x_{1} \exists y_{1} \phi)
\end{align}$$

I just expressed in purely FOL that each $y_{n}$ is dependent only on its corresponding $x_{n}$. This formula is not in Prenex Normal Form; and converting to it would indeed smash all the 'dependencies'. We already know that PNF preserves logical equivalence under classical logic, but not necessarily under other logics. Then Dependence Logic is another example.

Comment: "I just expressed in purely FOL that each $y_n$ is dependent only on its corresponding $x_n$." No, you didn't. Note that the third clause of your sentence is an immediate consequence of the first true (you've said "A, and B, and ("A iff B")" - this is just "A and B"). For an example of why this doesn't do what you want it to, take $\phi$ to be the statement "$x_1\not=y_1\wedge x_2\not=y_2\wedge (x_1=x_2\iff y_1=y_2)$." Intuitively, **when we add a Henkin quantifier to the front** $\phi$ says "the structure has an even (or infinite) number of elements." (cont'd)

Comment: However, any **three-element** structure satisfies the first-order sentence you've written! Suppose my domain is $\{a, b,c \}$; let's show that it satisfies $\forall x_1\exists y_1\forall x_2\exists y_2\phi$ (it will satisfy the second clause identically, and as remarked above the third clause is redundant). We can evaluate this by cases. Suppose WLOG you pick $x_1=a$; I'll pick $y_1=b$. Now if you pick $x_2=a$, I'll pick $y_2=b$; if you pick $x_2=b$, I'll pick $y_2=c$; and if you pick $x_2=c$ I'll pick $y_2=a$. And $3$ isn't even. In fact, your sentence holds iff the domain has size $>1$.

Comment: "your sentence [with @Noah's $\phi$] holds iff the domain has size $>1$." Yes. As does the Henkin-quantified form with $\exists f, g$ : $x_1 \neq f(x_1) \wedge x_2 \neq g(x_2) \wedge (x_1 = x_2 \Longleftrightarrow f(x_1) = g(x_2) ).$    "the third clause ... is an immediate consequence ..." Yes. Any two of those conjuncts is sufficient.